# How to install New Relic Agent on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, newrelic

I've some PHP projects on my Windows Server 2008 which uses WAMP server. I would like to install New Relic Agent for one of my PHP websites, but I couldn't find any guides for WAMP users.

Is there anyone who tried to install the New Relic Agent on WAMP?
If so, how can I install it?

Please don't just redirect to a document that has nothing to do with WAMP. I've already read a lot of documentation containing no information about WAMP server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New Relic currently doesn't have PHP agent for windows. The [FAQ](https://newrelic.com/docs/php/php-agent-faq#windows) confirms this. If you want to install New Relic agent for PHP, you have to use any of the OS [listed here](https://newrelic.com/docs/php/new-relic-for-php#requirements).